# INSERT INTO two tables at same time in one query,MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert-into

I use MS Access and I have a database with two tables:`Customers` and `UnlockRecords`. Fields of Customers table are:

> ID, Customer_Name, Customer_FamilyName, Home_Address

And fields of UnlockRecords table are:

> ID, Unlock_Date, Store

Now I want to insert data at the same time in to two tables Customers and UnlockRecords in one query.So I write this code in `SQL view` of query designer of Access:

> INSERT INTO Customers ( ID, Customer_Name, Customer_FamilyName,
>   Home_Address) SELECT
>   123 AS Expr1, "name" AS Expr2, "family" AS Expr3, " " AS Expr4, 
>    INSERT INTO UnlockRecords ( ID, Unlock_Date, Store) VALUES (2,"000000",3);

But I can not save or run query because this error occurs:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query. (Error 3067)

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: If the problem lies in not wanting either insert to execute unless both do, you should use transactions. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You have to use two separate queries.